# Regex to match either 4 or 5 digits before a letter

Tags: java, regex

I need to match either letter `A` preceded by `1-5` digits or letter `B` preceded by `1-4` digits.

So my regex looks like this:
`(\d{1,5}A)|(\d{1,4}B)`

But this matches the last 4 digits before an `A`.

Any solutions?

Comment: What's the problem exactly? do you only want to match `A` or `B`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> this matches the last 4 digits before an A

Require the item before your regex to *not* be preceded by a digit:

```
(?<!\d)((\d{1,5}A)|(\d{1,4}B))
```

Another solution is to require a *word boundary* with `\b`.

[lookahead/lookbehind tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: [`\b`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) could do the job as well.

Comment: I don't understand the problem and don't understand why this should be a solution. Your regex still "matches the last 4 digits before an A"

Comment: The last 5 digits before A would mean that there could be more than 5 digits before A, and your solution makes sense. If the regexp matches 4 digits before an A, it means there are exactly 4 digits.

Comment: @EricDuminil If the string is `123456789A`, OP doesn't want to see a match at all. Instead, he sees `56789A` returned as a match.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: In that case, OP would see 5 digits before A, not just 4.

Comment: @EricDuminil I think he mistyped, it should have been either "5 digits before A" or "4 digits before B".

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:

```
(\d{1,5}A)|(\d{1,4}B)
```

I would advise taking a look at [cheatsheet](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx). if you are unfamiliar with regular expressions and try to do these kind of simple regexs yourself.

There is also plenty of online regex testing apps such as: [regextester](https://regex101.com/) which enable you to test your regexes without writing any code.